# How to show image from network in flutter BoxDecoration?

Tags: image, flutter

I want to show an image of the network in BoxDecoration. But its showing error

> "The argument type 'image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'imageProvider'".

Here is the code where I am trying to show an image from the network inside box decoration. Please check and do let me know where I am wrong in this code.

```dart
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    image: new DecorationImage(image: new Image.network("http://myurl.com/"+productList[index].thumbnail),
    fit: BoxFit.cover)
),
```

Comment: The following code correction was submitted as an edit by @Saeed. Saeed: Please submit the solution as an answer rather than an edit. `dart
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    image: new DecorationImage(image: new Image.network("http://myurl.com/"+productList[index].thumbnail),
    image: new DecorationImage(image: new Image.network("http://myurl.com/"+productList[index].thumbnail).image,
    fit: BoxFit.cover)
    fit: BoxFit.cover)
),
),`

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I've resolved the issue, it can be achieved using this code.

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage("urlImage"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover)
    ),
```

Comment: How to use cachednetwork image ? I can't use the provider `'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'`

Comment: This doesn't work in new flutter `The argument type 'DecorationImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.`

Answer (score 15):

**if you want to load CachedNetworkImage then use in this way**
*** https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150",
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: imageProvider,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter:
              ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.colorBurn)),
    ),
  ),
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

Comment: Thanx for the effort but I dont see how to put this as box decoration of a container.

Comment: `'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'`

Answer (score 6):

Ammy's answer is right. However I would like to the answer my experience of using BoxDecoration().

To apply background image either from the Internet or from assets in Flutter app, we can use DecorationImage() class in image property of BoxDecoration().

Below is a code snippet, where background image is applied from an image from a URL in the Flutter app:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage('https://www.exampledomain.com/images/background.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
  ),
```

)

So, to apply background image in Container widget, we have to use decoration property. In the decoration property we supply a new BoxDecoration() object and this object should have an image property which points to the image resource URL. In the above snippet, image propery is instantiated a NetworkImage() object which is pointing to an image URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  
  String url = "";          //your url
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: new DecorationImage(
          image: new NetworkImage(url),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

###### If you are using decoration for `backgroundImage` and want to use `CachedNetworkImage` as `backgroundImage`.

You have to set background of the `Container` using `Stack`,i.e convert this to

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage('backgroundimage.img'), <-- Your Background image
    ),
  ),
 child: [ Your Foreground Widgets ]
)
```

to

```
Stack(
      children: [
        CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: image,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
       [ Your Foreground Widgets ]
     ]
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  decoration:BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image:FileImage(
        File(your_image_path),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```