# how to pass the value to a file path in dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my app i am displaying several cards,each card which contains title,description and a image on it.  I am taking the name of the image to be displayed from the json response i.e,icon field.

and i have that image with the name I got in my JSON response in my assets/name.png.

I am not getting how can I fetch the image i.e how to pass that path.

below is small snippet of my code.

```dart
createCard(BuildContext context, int count, var data) {
var colorFromJSON = data[count]['jsonString']['color'];
//here I am getting the name of the image from the icon field in the JSON Response
var iconName = data[count]['jsonString']['icon'];
var noHashColor = colorFromJSON.substring(1);
var colorHex = 0xFF000000 + int.parse(noHashColor, radix: 16);
if (data[count]['jsonString']['reportType'] == currentReportSummaryType) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
            setGenerateReportView(context, count, data);
            },
            child: Container(

            //here I am adding 
                decoration: getCardDecoration(
                    "assets/dot_line_chart.png", new Color(colorHex)),

                instead of hardcoding the image name as dot_line_chart.png, I
                want it to be like contents of iconName field with png.
            like "assets/iconName.png" how to do this


            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.931,
            height: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .height * 0.16,
            child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(image: new NetworkImage(data[count]['imageName']['reportType']),
      fit: BoxFit.cover)
    ),
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714191/6450434